# How do I read/write C# BigIntegers to/from a file?

Tags: c#, serialization, biginteger

in one of my classes, I have a routine that reads and writes an array of type Decimal (using `BinaryReader` / `BinaryWriter`'s `ReadDecimal()` and `Write()` methods, to wit:

```
BinaryReader inputReader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(BaseFilePath));
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < m_Codes[x].GetLength(0); y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < m_Codes[x].GetLength(1); z++) {
            m_Codes[x][y, z] = inputReader.ReadDecimal();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < m_Codes[x].GetLength(0); y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < m_Codes[x].GetLength(1); z++) {
            outputWriter.Write(m_Codes[x][y, z]);
        }
    }
}
```

.. as you can see, only the first dimension is known at design time, the others vary on runtime.

In a perfect world, I would replace `ReadDecimal()` with `ReadBigInteger()` and something similar for the writing methods, but that does not seem to be supported in the Stream classes; I'm guessing this is because BigInteger can be of any length.

About the best thing I can think of is to "hand code" the BigInteger, by converting it to a `byte[]` array, then writing the length of that array, then writing each byte in the array itself (and doing the reverse to read it in)

Two questions:

1) Is this a better way?

2) I'm primarily motivated by a desire to increase performance; boes BigInteger even perform that much better than Decimal, if at all?

Comment: Do you _need_ better performance?

Comment: What is not so good with Decimal?

Comment: @Tigran: Decimal's performances are far worse than that of primitive types like int, long, float or double. I don't know though how they compare to BigInteger

Comment: I do, indeed, need better performance, not on the I/O loop itself of course, but the program that does calculations with these figures involves brute force calculations of probabilities of games where the total number of outcomes goes well past a simple _long_, and the calculation involves many levels of nested loops repeating.  I'm aware of the perils of premature optimization, I assure you :)

Comment: I think builtin performance of Decimal can not be worse then custom tricks to make save BigInt. At least it would be surprising to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert to a string ([`BigInteger.ToSting()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.tostring.aspx)) and then write that string (as strings are directly supported with [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring.aspx) and [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx) this avoids needing to do any encoding/decoding yourself).

Then convert it back with [`BigInteger.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.parse.aspx).

To address the performance: I think you'll need to measure for the cases you are interested.

When relatively small values (say abs(value) < 2<sup>128</sup>) I would *expect* `BigInteger`'s performance to be within a couple of orders of magnitude of `long`'s performance (ie. no more than ~500 times slower). But as `BigInteger` instances get larger operations will take longer (more bits have to be manipulated). On the other hand `decimal` should have reasonably consistent performance at all scales, but it could be very much slower than `long` for numbers in the intersection of their ranges (`decimal` is a much more complex representation: scale factors and retaining actual significant digits through calculations; but no intuition of the effect of this complexity).

And remember: `BigDecimal` is exact – it never rounds; `decimal` is approximate – data can fall off the end and be thrown away. It seems unlikely that any one business problem would support either.

Answer (score 5):

There's one fairly simple approach: Call [`BigDecimal.ToByteArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.tobytearray.aspx) to serialize, and the [`BigDecimal(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207.aspx) constructor when deserializing. Admittedly that ends up copying the data, but I'd still expect it to be reasonably fast.

What's of more concern to you: serialization performance or arithmetic performance?

As for any speed differences between `BigInteger` and `decimal` - you should test it for the operations you actually want to perform, being aware that they will behave differently (e.g. dividing 3 by 2 will obviously give a different answer for each type).